# how to display unique dropdown elements in HTML

Tags: php, html, laravel

```
 <select class="form-control" id="SAMPLE_ID" name="SAMPLE_ID"  >
           <option value="1">sample 1</option>                  
           <option value="2">sample 2</option> 
           <option value="1">sample 1</option>       
           <option value="2">sample 2</option> 
 </select>
```

hi..
i have the repeating values,i want to remove the repeated values and display unique value and name to the above dropdown list. i am unable to find any predefind function html or php.
please help me out

```
<select class="form-control" id="SAMPLE_ID" name="SAMPLE_ID" > 
<?php 
    foreach($lists as $list): 
?> 
    <option value="{{($list->sampletid)}}">{{$list->samplename}}</option‌​> 
<?php 
    endforeach; 
?> 
</select>
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this before the select box is rendered? Or after the page loads?

Comment: How are you getting this though? Did you do an sql query to create an object? Looped through an object?

Comment: <select class="form-control" id="SAMPLE_ID" name="SAMPLE_ID"  >
                                                    
<?php foreach($lists as $list): ?> 
                                                    
<option value="{{($list->sampletid)}}">{{$list->samplename}}</option>
                                                    
<?php endforeach; ?>
                                                    
</select>

Comment: JS is probably the easiest solution at this point.

Comment: You could iterate through all values and push them to an array, before pushing each instance, you would check if the value doesn't equal a value that already exists in the array, then once you have your array built you would repopulate that select list with the remaining unique values - just a suggestion worth exploring, or one that might point you in the right direction. depending on when and where these values are extracted from, you could do this client side (javascript) or server side (php)

Comment: @mouli - you can try php array_unique() and get the unique data from backend, instead of sorting in frontend.

Comment: Please show how you create `$lists`

Comment: The code you show us, cannot produce the output you claim it does

Answer (score 1):

first get the id and name like this

```
      <?php
      $saples = [];
      foreach ($lists as $list){
        $saples[$list->sampletid] = $list->samplename;
    }
    //$saples = array_unique($saples); no need of this because the repeating index will replace automatically

    ?>
```

then go with your unique id and name

```
<select class="form-control" id="SAMPLE_ID" name="SAMPLE_ID" >
<?php
foreach($saples as $k=>$v):
?>
<option value="{{$k}}">{{$v}}</option‌​>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```